# How to pass agrs to mapreduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have to pass 3rd agrs to mapreduce program..
I have to read file given by user in mapreduce program.

Comment: Please rewrite your question with full words (agrs = ?) and more details, such as what you have already attempted. An actual question (with a proper question mark) would also be nice...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a jar to run, then the answer is:

```
hadoop jar <jarfile> <main> <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
```